# JavaScript array reorder in circle

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I have javascript array that looks like this

```
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

And I have a setInterval function on every second. And each time function is triggered I need to reorder the array to looks like this [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1] and next time [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]... Whats the best way to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's pretty simple: Use a combination of [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```js
var myArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(myArr.join());

var myInterval = setInterval(
    function (){
        myArr.push(myArr.shift());
        console.log(myArr.join());
    },
    1000
);
```

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) runs the supplied function every x milliseconds (`1000`, in this case),
[`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first element from the array it's called on, and returns it,
[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds the supplied parameter to the end of the array it's called on.

---

You can reverse the direction using [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) and [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```js
var myArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(myArr.join());

var myInterval = setInterval(
    function (){
        myArr.unshift(myArr.pop());
        console.log(myArr.join());
    },
    1000
);
```